# Every deploy from visualstudio.com cleans Azure hosting space

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

I'm using visualstudio.com to deploy to a azure site. It works fine, but on every deployment it removes all files from the space in azure.

I have user uploaded content, so it would be nice if it at least one folder remained.

Comment: I suspect this is by design. You shouldn't have uploaded content in the website itself, but in a separate area. I don't know how to do that in Azure, or indeed if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Azure deployment works by default.

You can add a publish profile to your build definition to stop this from happening.

Download a publish profile from your Azure portal, and under `Settings->File Publish Options` make sure `Remove additional files at destination` is not ticked. Save this profile then add this to your build definition in Team Explorer.

Ideally though you shouldn't upload content to the site itself, as the site is copied out to each virtual machine that hosts it. These multiple instances will lead to data integrity problems if the same user data is modified on two different instances. (Though you can get away with it, if only ever one instance... but it is at the least bad practice for Azure...)

Comment: Thanks. I'm very new to azure. I'm trying to deploy Umbraco to Azure. That uses a media directory to store the user uploaded images. What do do with that?

Comment: Check this link out to set your media path in the appSettings part of your web.config: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/15541-Different-location-for-Media-folder